# PHP SoapClient missing data

Tags: php, soap, zend-framework2, soap-client

I'm using a SoapClient (zend2), but for some reasons, can't get complete data answer

```
$client = new \SoapClient($host);
$result = $client->getInvoice();
```

$result var_dump:

```
["ListInvoiceResult"] => object(stdClass)#282 (4) {
["Status"] => int(1)
["ErrorCode"] => NULL
["ErrorMessage"] => string(0) ""
["Invoice"] => array(1436) {
[0] => object(stdClass)#283 (3) {
["ID"] => int(12741)
["Date"] => string(10) "2011.01.31"
["DateSales"] => string(10) "2011.01.31"
}
```

Above object missing a variable **InvoiceNumber**

But when I call __getLastResponse method , I've recieved complete data with InvoiceNumber

```
 <p1:Invoice>
<p1:ID>12741</p1:ID>
<p1:InvoiceNumber>1|FA|2011|00633</p1:InvoiceNumber>
<p1:Date>2011.01.31</p1:Date>
<p1:DateSales>2011.01.31</p1:DateSales>
</p1:Invoice>
```

Hmmm. Looks strange. But all other methods returns complete data, even variable Invoice Number..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using the *classmap* option in SoapClient or check you mapped classes, for instance:

```
class MyBook {
public $title;
public $author;
}

$server = new SoapClient("books.wsdl", array('classmap' => array('book' => "MyBook")));
```

In your case you should model ListInvoiceResult and Invoice class for instance:

```
class WS_ListInvoiceResult {
public $Status;
public $ErrorCode;
public $ErrorMessage;
public $Invoice;
}

class WS_Invoice {
public $ID;
public $Date;
public $DateSales;
public $InvoiceNumber;
}
```

And connect to soap api as such:

```
$server = new SoapClient("wsdl path", array('classmap' => array("ListInvoiceResult" => "WS_ListInvoiceResult", "Invoice" => "WS_Invoice")));
```

If this doesn't help try checking your WSDL, though based on the response it appears to be OK.